# Checkmark is not displayed in caption

Tags: floats, symbols

I tried to display checkmark in a figure caption, but i am getting "undefined control sequence" as error. Note that i can normally display it  in a text.

```
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage{bbm} 
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{pifont}
\makeatletter
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 
\usepackage{graphics}
```

The part used in the caption:

```
\begin{figure}%[H]
\begin{centering}
\includegraphics[scale=0.45]{Fig}
\par\end{centering}
\caption{some text \checkmark} 
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `\def`, it will not warn you if you overwrite existing commands. Beside this you need to define a robust command as you want to use it in a caption.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xparse} 
\RenewDocumentCommand\checkmark{}{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%[H]
\centering 
figure
\caption{some text \checkmark}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I add another MWE for your question:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}%[H]
\centering 
\includegraphics[scale=0.4]{example-image-c}
\caption{Here there is a checkmark symbol in caption \checkmark}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]